# ReactJS + Redux props from mapStateToProps do not refresh on dispatching action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

After dispatching action props do not changed. My redux container:

```
class ConnectedAppContent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="content">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <PropsRoute path="/login" component={LoginForm} doLogin={this.props.doLogin} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/scan" redirectTo="/login" component={Scanner} token={this.props.token} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/result" redirectTo="/login" component={ParsedQRCode} token={this.props.token} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        token: state.token,
        parsedQRCode: state.parsedQRCode
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    doLogin: token => dispatch(doLogin(token))
});

export const AppContent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ConnectedAppContent);
```

And main `App` component, wrapped into `Provider`:

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <AppHeader />
                <AppContent />
                <AppFooter />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('.wrapper')
)
```

What I should do for props updating? Props are binded with initial state but do not refresh after `doLogin`.

**UPDATED**

My reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    token: null
}

export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DO_LOGIN:
            return {...state, token: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And `doLogin` action:

```
export const doLogin = token => ({
    type: DO_LOGIN,
    payload: token
})
```

And `PrivateRoute` component (I got it from [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105)):

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component, redirectTo, ...rest }) => {
    // rest.token is undefined here, even after dispatching doLogin
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => {
            return !!rest.token ? (
                renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest)
            ) : (
                <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: redirectTo,
                    state: { from: routeProps.location }
                }}/>
            );
        }}/>
    );
};
```

And `PropsRoute` (also from [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105)):

```
export const PropsRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => {
            return renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest);
        }}/>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please show the doLogin function and the corresponding reducer.

Comment: Please share the reducer for the action, the component should update if you are updating token or parsedQRCode

Comment: @RyanC please see updated question

Comment: @EdwinVargas updated

Comment: btw, token updates in the mapStateToProps, as I can see from console.log

Comment: Be sure that the code in the reducer is being executed, I mean, inside the DO_LOGIN case

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I got this component from https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar added to the question

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar PropsRoute also do not receive updated token as props

Comment: Try `case DO_LOGIN: { console.log('will this appear?') }`

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar yes, this appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, caught the culprit: (It should be loginReducer's  token)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        token: state.loginReducer.token,
```

Comment: Sure! Thank you very match

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are expecting the prop `token` value on the `Scanner` component that you are binding to routes, in which case React router does not pass props to childrens.

I would discourage you to pass props to routes and instead make all your routes components container components, but if for some reason you think this wont be an issue than one way of passing props to children in router is :

```
<PrivateRoute path="/scan" redirectTo="/login" component={() => <Scanner token={this.props.token}>}/>
```

Comment: But token also undefined in my `PrivateRoute` component. I will add it to the question in few minutes

Comment: `PrivateRoute` component was added to the question

Comment: I will try... how to post it ? I never done this before

Comment: Thanks for useful info about passing props from `Router` to children